# ASP MVC 4 not found log4net on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, crystal-reports

In my code I using Crystal Reports and it's work fine with ASP.NET WebForms. Now I make similar app on ASP MVC with same web.config and c# code, When I run it throw an error in MVC Web.config file at line 55:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Line 53: <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 54: <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 55: <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 56: <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
Line 57: <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and just commented out the log4net line and it worked for me.